# Only allow signups from people with @___.com emails

Tags: users, emails

I want users to be able to signup to my Craft site, but only if they have a specific email domain. So:

```
*@gmail.com
*@hotmail.com
```

Would be allowed, but anyone with a *yahoo.com* email, for example, would not be able to sign up. I can do client-side validation but is there anything I can do in Craft?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is to write a custom plugin that intercepts the [`users.onBeforeSaveUser` event](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onBeforeSaveUser).

You would check that the submitted email address matched your desired pattern and set `$event->performAction = false` if the criteria wasn't met. This would prevent the user from being saved.

So the `init()` method of your plugin might look something like this:

```
    public function init()
    {
        craft()->on('users.beforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {

            // Retrieve the userModel from the event
            $user = $event->params['user'];
            $isNewUser = $event->params['isNewUser'];

            // Check if this is a front end request and that we are dealing with a new user
            if (craft()->request->isSiteRequest() && $isNewUser) {

                // Check for valid email address
                if (email address doesn't match required pattern) {
                    // Cancel user save
                    $event->preformAction = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but I should have prefaced my question by saying I know zero PHP. Can you give detailed steps on how to implement this?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out! Thank you so much for your help!